# How to convert Paradox to Excel

Tags: excel, python-2.7, paradox

I am trying to work with Paradox files and convert these to an Excel file.

Does anyone know how to achieve such conversion?

Comment: yes, but , must be a open source software,thanks enyway

Comment: Is this a one-time migration or are you creating a process with .DB files among its inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a small Python script to read Paradox .DB files.
But please be careful, it's not complete: some field types may not be converted (only memos AFAIK, but I'm not a Paradox expert).

https://gist.github.com/BertrandBordage/9892556

You can either read a .DB file as Python objects using `paradox.read('your_file.DB')` or convert it to a CSV file using `paradox.to_csv('your_file.DB')`.